# Creo Parametric OBJECT TOOLKIT - Passing Variables in Event Listener Classes

Tags: c++

I am developing some code to run synchronously with a 3D Software Program.

I've created a menu using its tools, but, by default, I can't pass variables from different features that are connected to Action Listeners. I'll post the multiple snippets of code that are spread across multiple files (from my 3D software API) that are relevant to a single function.
I wanted to know what should I edit in these files in order to NOT use global variables (which is what will ultimately happen if I can't figure this out).

I omitted the code to the other controls. What I want is to pass a variable through the I_NomeInputPanelListener(), but here's my main code (which creates the Dialog).

```
        uifcDialog_ptr parafusos = uifcDialogFind(PARAFUSOS_DIALOG, PARAFUSOS_DIALOG);
        ParafusosDialogListener *parafusosLis = new ParafusosDialogListener();
        parafusos->AddActionListener(parafusosLis);

        i_diametro = uifcOptionMenuFind(PARAFUSOS_DIALOG, PARAFUSOS_I_DIAMETRO);
        I_DiametroOptionMenuListener *i_diametroLis = new I_DiametroOptionMenuListener();
        i_diametro->AddActionListener(i_diametroLis);

        status = uifcActivateDialog(PARAFUSOS_DIALOG);
```

This is on my header file:

```
        class I_DiametroOptionMenuListener : public uifcDefaultOptionMenuListener
        {
            public:
            I_DiametroOptionMenuListener() {}
            ~I_DiametroOptionMenuListener() {}

            void OnItemSelect(uifcOptionMenu_ptr handle);
        };
```

This code exist on the Software API files:

```
        class uifcDefaultOptionMenuListener : public uifcOptionMenuListener
        {
            void                OnItemSelect (uifcOptionMenu_ptr handle) {}
        };
```

---

```
        class uifcOptionMenuListener : virtual public uifcComponentListener
        {
            xaideclare (uifcOptionMenuListener)

            protected:
            virtual ~uifcOptionMenuListener ()
            {
            }

            public:
            virtual void        OnItemSelect (uifcOptionMenu_ptr handle) = 0;
        };
```

---

```
        class uifcComponentListener : virtual public xobject
        {
            xaideclare (uifcComponentListener)

        public:
            virtual ~uifcComponentListener ()
            {
            }
        };
```

I've tried adding a ",int var)" to all the functions OnItemSelect in all the classes, but I tried to print an int = 10 and I got something like hundreds of millions.

I don't know if you can help me with this or if I should be messing with these files in the first place. Regardless, any suggestion that helps me not use Global Variables is welcomed.

Comment: You will have a higher chance of getting help if you [edit] the question to say which framework/API/3D software you are working with (and add the corresponding tags).

Comment: Also, make a [mcve]. I'm sure you don't need more than one event handler to show what you're trying to do.